# Some part of HTML code is not showing

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, web-deployment

I am very beginners with web developing. I am a problem which is difficult for me to solve.
The bellow part of my HTML code is not showing:

```
<div class="DTED_Lightbox_Content"  id="DTED_Lightbox_Content1"  tabindex="-1" style="width: 40%;display: none;position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;z-index: 1000" >
    <div class="DTE DTE_Action_Create">
        <div data-dte-e="processing" class="DTE_Processing_Indicator"  id="DTE_Processing_Indicator1" style="display:none"></div>
        <div data-dte-e="head" class="DTE_Header">
            <div data-dte-e="head_content" class="DTE_Header_Content">Edit Account Group </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="body" class="DTE_Body">
            <div data-dte-e="body_content" class="DTE_Body_Content" style="height: 400px;">
                <form data-dte-e="form" class="" style="display: block;">
                    <div data-dte-e="form_content" class="DTE_Form_Content">
                        <div id="peymethod1">
                            <table>
                                <tr><td>Account Name:</td><td><select id="account_name1">
                                            <option value="">Select account name </option>
                                            <?php
                                            $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
                                            $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
                                            if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                                foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                                                    echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="date3" value="" name="account-date"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Amount:</td><td><input type="text"  value="" name="account-amount" id="amount1"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Account Type:</td><td><select id="account_type1">
                                            <option value="">Select account Type</option>
                                            <option value="0">Debit</option>
                                            <option value="1">Credit</option>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Currency:</td><td><select id="currency1">
                                            <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                            <option value="2">EUR</option>
                                            <option value="1">USD</option>
                                        </select></td></tr> 
                                <tr><td>term:</td><td><textarea name="account_term" id="term1"></textarea></td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="">
                            <div data-dte-e="input" class=""> 
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-message" class="DTE_Field_Message"></div>
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-info" class="DTE_Field_Info"></div></div>
                        </div> 
                        <div data-dte-e="form_error" class="DTE_Form_Error" id="DTE_Form_Error1" style="display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div data-dte-e="form_clear" class="DTE_Form_Clear" id="DTE_Form_Clear1"></div>
                    </div></form></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="foot" class="DTE_Footer">
            <div data-dte-e="foot_content" class="DTE_Footer_Content">
                <div data-dte-e="form_buttons" class="DTE_Form_Buttons" id="DTE_Form_Buttons1"><button class="butt">Update</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Gid" id="Gid" value=""/>  </div></div></div></div>
    <div class="DTED_Lightbox_Close" id="DTED_Lightbox_Close1" ></div></div>
       <div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="display: none;z-index: 1;width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

I have also put the whole code for better understanding of the overal page:

```
<?php
require_once 'header.php';

?>
<style>
    #image:hover{
        width:20px;
        height:19px;
        border-right:1px solid blue;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    function aj() {

             $('#accounting').dataTable({
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            "bSort": true,
            'bDestroy': true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            'sPaginationType': "full_numbers",
            'iDisplayLength': 25,
            'sAjaxSource': 'admin/datatables/accounting/ledger.php?userID='+$('#users').val(),
aoColumns = [
{"mData":"count"},{"mData":"AccountID"},
{"mData":"Debit"},{"mData":"Credit"},
{ "mData": "CurrencyID"},
{"mData":"Date"},
{"mData":"Terms"},
{"mData":"Actions"}
]
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        aj();
        $("#DTED_Lightbox_Close1").click(function () {
            $("#DTED_Lightbox_Content1").show();
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
        });

        $("#DTE_Form_Buttons1").click(function () {
            var error = '';
            $("#DTE_Processing_Indicator1").show();
            id = $("#Gid").val();
            account_id = $("#account_name1").val();
            currency = $("#currency1").val();
            date = $("#date3").val();
            account_type = $("#account_type1").val();
            term = $("#term1").val();
            amount = $("#amount1").val();

            if ($.trim(account_id).length == 0)
            {

                error += 'account name can not be empty!!<br />';
            }
            if ($.trim(currency).length == 0)
            {

                error += 'please select a currency!<br>';
            }
            if ($.trim(account_type).length == 0)
            {
                error += 'please select a account type !<br>';

            }

            if ($.trim(amount).length == 0)
            {

                error += 'amount can not be empty<br />';
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'admin/ajax/get_ajax_functions.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ({'func': 'validate_digit', 'id': amount}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var jsonobj1 = JSON.parse(data);

                        if (jsonobj1.error == 1)
                        {
                            error = 5;
                            error += 'amount not valid!!<br />';
                            $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html(error);
                            exit();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }



            $("#DTE_Form_Error1").show();
            if (error != '') {
                $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html(error);
                $("#DTE_Processing_Indicator1").hide();
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'admin/ajax/get_ajax_functions.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ({'func': 'update_ledger', 'id': id, 'account_id': account_id, 'currency': currency, 'account_type': account_type, 'date': date, 'amount': amount, 'term': term}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);

                        if (jsonobj.error == '0') {
                            $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html("Account updated");
                        }
                        if (jsonobj.error == 1) {
                            //already
                            $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html("dont update!!");


                        }
                        if (jsonobj.error == 2) {
                            //dont inset
                            $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html("not avalable!!");

                        }

                        $("#DTE_Processing_Indicator1").hide();
                        aj();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#error_var").html('');
            error = 0;
            err_str = '';
            account_id = $("#account_name").val();
            currency = $("#currency").val();
            date = $("#date2").val();
            account_type = $("#account_type").val();
            term = $("#term").val();
            amount = $("#amount").val();

            if ($.trim(account_id).length == 0)
            {
                error = 1;
                err_str += 'account name can not be empty!!<br />';
            }
            if ($.trim(currency).length == 0)
            {
                error = 2;
                err_str += 'please select a currency!<br>';
            }
            if ($.trim(account_type).length == 0)
            {
                err_str += 'please select a account type !<br>';
                error = 3;
            }

            if ($.trim(amount).length == 0)
            {
                error = 4;
                err_str += 'amount can not be empty<br />';
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'admin/ajax/get_ajax_functions.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ({'func': 'validate_digit', 'id': amount}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var jsonobj1 = JSON.parse(data);

                        if (jsonobj1.error == 1)
                        {
                            error = 5;
                            err_str += 'amount not valid!!<br />';
                            div = '<div  class="text_information" align="center"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td><div class="imgwarning"></div></td><td><b>Please correct the following errors to continue!</b></td></tr></table><ol>' + err_str + '</ol></div>';
                            $("#error_var").html(div);
                            exit();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            if (error == 0) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'admin/ajax/get_ajax_functions.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ({'func': 'insert_ledger', 'account_id': account_id, 'currency': currency, 'account_type': account_type, 'date': date, 'amount': amount, 'term': term}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (jsonobj.error == 1)
                        {
                            $("#error_var").html('<div  class="text_information" align="center"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td><div class="imgwarning"></div></td><td><b>Please correct the following errors to continue!</b></td></tr></table><ol>error at inserting</ol></div>');
                        } else {
                            $("#error_var").html('<div  class="text_information" align="center" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(88, 28, 225); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td><div class=""></div></td><td><b>Inserted SuccessFul</b></td></tr></table></div>');

                            aj();

                            $("#account_name").val('');
                            $("#amount").val('');
                            $("#group_id").val('');
                            $("#account_type").val('');
                            $("#currency").val('');
                            $("#date2").val('');
                            $("#term").val('');
                        }


                    }
                });

            } else {
                div = '<div  class="text_information" align="center"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td><div class="imgwarning"></div></td><td><b>Please correct the following errors to continue!</b></td></tr></table><ol>' + err_str + '</ol></div>';
                $("#error_var").html(div);
            }
        });

    });

    function edit_ledger(id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/ajax/get_ajax_functions.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: ({'func': 'get_leger', 'id': id}),
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jsonobj.error == '0') {
                    var x = $("#edittr" + id).offset().left;
                    var y = $("#edittr" + id).offset().top;
                    var yd = $("#apppage").offset().top;
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', yd);
                    $('#DTED_Lightbox_Content1').css('top', y - 100)

                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
                    $("#DTED_Lightbox_Content1").attr('z-index', '10000');
                    $("#DTED_Lightbox_Content1").css("opacity", "1");
                    $("#DTE_Form_Clear1").html('');
                    $("#DTE_Processing_Indicator1").hide();
                    $("#DTED_Lightbox_Content1").show();
                    $("#DTE_Form_Error1").html('');
                    $("#account_name1").val(jsonobj.account_name);
                    $("#account_type1").val(jsonobj.account_type);
                    $("#currency1").val(jsonobj.currency);
                    $("#amount1").val(jsonobj.amount);
                    $("#date3").val(jsonobj.date3);
                    $("#term1").val(jsonobj.term);
                    $("#Gid").val(id);

                } else
                    alert('no get data');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<br/>
<table width="99.5%">
    <tr><td>
            <ul id="menupre"  >

                <li  class="current">
                    <a href="index.php" style="padding-top: 10px">    <b>Ledger</b></a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="ledger_accounts.php"> <b>Accounts</b></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ledger_account_groups.php"> <b>Account Groups</b></a>

                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="accounting-report.php"> <b>Report</b></a>

                </li>
            </ul>

        </td></tr></tbody></table>
<table width="70%" class="PortfolioTable" align="left">
    <tbody> 
        <tr><td>
                <div class="add_img"> <a  id="add" onclick="$('#leg').toggle('slow');" >add new</a> </div>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>   
                <div id="leg" style="padding: 10px 20px ! important; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 10px 0px 40px ! important;display: none">
                    <span class="error" id="error_var"></span>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Account Name:</td><td><select id="account_name">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
                                    $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
                                    if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                        foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                                            echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            <?php
                             if (empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                  echo '<font color=red>Please <a href="ledger_accounts.php" >add accounts</a></font>';
                             }
                            ?>
                            </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="date2" value="" name="account-date"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Amount:</td><td><input type="text"  value="" name="account-amount" id="amount"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Account Type:</td><td><select id="account_type">
                                    <option value="">Select account Type</option>
                                    <option value="0">Debit</option>
                                    <option value="1">Credit</option>
                                </select></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Currency:</td><td><select id="currency">
                                    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                    <option value="2">EUR</option>
                                    <option value="1">USD</option>
                                </select></td></tr> 
                        <tr><td>term:</td><td><textarea name="account_term" id="term"></textarea></td></tr>

                        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" /></td></tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>

                <div id=dynamic style="margin-top:2px;z-index: 10"> 
                    <div style="margin: 0px 0 30px 0; float: right;">
 <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                       <select onchange="aj();" id="users">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
                                    $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
                                    if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                        foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                                        echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    ?>
                       </select>
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                        <input type="button" onclick="aj()" value="search" /> 
                    </div>

                    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 class=display id=accounting>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width=10><font size="2">#</font></th> 
                                <th width=80><font>Account Name</font></th>
                                <th width=40><font>Debit</font></th>
                                <th width=40><font>Credit</font></th>
                                <th width=20><font>Currency</font></th>
                                <th width=60><font>Date</font></th>
                                <th><font>Terms</font></th>

                                <th width=80><font></font></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
<!-- There is nothing is loaded here -->
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
 <tr>
                                <th width=10><font size="2">#</font></th> 
                                <th width=80><font>Account Name</font></th>
                                <th width=40><font>Debit</font></th>
                                <th width=40><font>Credit</font></th>
                                <th width=20><font>Currency</font></th>
                                <th width=60><font>Date</font></th>
                                <th><font>Terms</font></th>

                                <th width=80><font></font></th>
                            </tr>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class='spacer'></div>
            </td></tr></tbody></table> 
<br /><br /><br /><br /> 

<div class="DTED_Lightbox_Content"  id="DTED_Lightbox_Content1"  tabindex="-1" style="width: 40%;display: none;position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;z-index: 1000" >
    <div class="DTE DTE_Action_Create">
        <div data-dte-e="processing" class="DTE_Processing_Indicator"  id="DTE_Processing_Indicator1" style="display:none"></div>
        <div data-dte-e="head" class="DTE_Header">
            <div data-dte-e="head_content" class="DTE_Header_Content">Edit Account Group </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="body" class="DTE_Body">
            <div data-dte-e="body_content" class="DTE_Body_Content" style="height: 400px;">
                <form data-dte-e="form" class="" style="display: block;">
                    <div data-dte-e="form_content" class="DTE_Form_Content">
                        <div id="peymethod1">
                            <table>
                                <tr><td>Account Name:</td><td><select id="account_name1">
                                            <option value="">Select account name </option>
                                            <?php
                                            $Acc = new BLL\Accounts;
                                            $Acc->get($arrayOfObjects);
                                            if (!empty($arrayOfObjects)) {
                                                foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $value) {
                                                    echo "<option value=" . $value->getID() . "> " . $value->getAccountName() . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="date3" value="" name="account-date"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Amount:</td><td><input type="text"  value="" name="account-amount" id="amount1"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Account Type:</td><td><select id="account_type1">
                                            <option value="">Select account Type</option>
                                            <option value="0">Debit</option>
                                            <option value="1">Credit</option>
                                        </select></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Currency:</td><td><select id="currency1">
                                            <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                            <option value="2">EUR</option>
                                            <option value="1">USD</option>
                                        </select></td></tr> 
                                <tr><td>term:</td><td><textarea name="account_term" id="term1"></textarea></td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="">
                            <div data-dte-e="input" class=""> 
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-message" class="DTE_Field_Message"></div>
                                <div data-dte-e="msg-info" class="DTE_Field_Info"></div></div>
                        </div> 
                        <div data-dte-e="form_error" class="DTE_Form_Error" id="DTE_Form_Error1" style="display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div data-dte-e="form_clear" class="DTE_Form_Clear" id="DTE_Form_Clear1"></div>
                    </div></form></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dte-e="foot" class="DTE_Footer">
            <div data-dte-e="foot_content" class="DTE_Footer_Content">
                <div data-dte-e="form_buttons" class="DTE_Form_Buttons" id="DTE_Form_Buttons1"><button class="butt">Update</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Gid" id="Gid" value=""/>  </div></div></div></div>
    <div class="DTED_Lightbox_Close" id="DTED_Lightbox_Close1" ></div></div>




<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="display: none;z-index: 1;width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>


<?php
require_once 'footer.php';
?><br />
```

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Narrow down your code to the problem and elaborate your question.

Comment: "Some part" WHAT part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display:none;` from the style of the top `DIV`

Comment: how about the other display:none; ? should I remove all of them?

Comment: Only the divs you want to see lol